# how to store result in list from a for loop

Tags: r, loops

I'm new to R, this may be a silly question, but I don't know how to resolve.

I have a for loop which will return possibly i*j non-empty elements.

I want to store all the non-empty result in a list, but if I use  `result[[i]]<-tmp` in the loop, it can only store up to `i` elements, how am I able to store all values in a list? Thanks

```
  result<-list()
  for (i in 1:nrow(m)){
    for (j in 1:i){
      if(m[i,j]!=0 && m[j,i]!=0){
        num=min(m[i,j],m[j,i])
        tmp=c(i,j,num)
        result[[i]]<-tmp
      }
    }
  }

sample data
set.seed(123)
m= matrix(sample(0:5, size = 5*5, replace = TRUE), ncol = 5)
```

Desired

```
 row col min
[1] 1 1 1
[1] 2 2 3
[1] 3 1 2
[1] 3 2 2
[1] 3 3 4
[1] 4 1 5
[1] 4 2 1
[1] 4 4 1
[1] 5 1 5
[1] 5 2 2
[1] 5 4 5
[1] 5 5 3
```

Per David's answer

```
pmin(mx[upper.tri(mx, diag = TRUE)], mx[lower.tri(mx, diag = TRUE)])

[1] 1 0 2 5 2 3 5 1 0 1 3 0 1 5 3
```

returns

```
      > result
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 2 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 3 3 4

[[4]]
[1] 4 4 2

[[5]]
[1] 5 5 4
```

Comment: For loops and growing lists in R are both very slow. Can you rethink your algorithm as a function applied over each element of the matrix and use `apply()`?

Comment: Aren't you basically computing `pmin(m, t(m))`?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do and what exactly not working. You also don't need such big data set in order reproduce your problem. I think something like `m = matrix(sample.int(5, size = 5*5, replace = TRUE), ncol = 5)` should do. Also use `set.seed` and show what you are expecting to get from your `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks all, I'm trying to compare the values in symmetric positions along the diagonal of the matrix and return the minimum value...

Comment: good point, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: For `set.seed(123); m = matrix(sample.int(5, size = 5*5, replace = TRUE), ncol = 5)`, what is the desired result? Please show the actual values you want to get.

Comment: per your example, I'll be expecting a list of 12, but my code only returns a list of 5

Comment: A list of 12? Containing what values?

Comment: Hi, I updated the example in the original post, thank you.

Comment: How about `pmin(m[upper.tri(m, diag = TRUE)], m[lower.tri(m, diag = TRUE)])`?

Comment: Thanks David, that's very neat. But I have a question that, the result from real data contains many 0s. I only want to get the row and column index for the non-zeros, as in the form of the expected. Is there a way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: You need to use `@` in order to ping me. Other than that, for the data set of `set.seed(123); m= matrix(sample(0:5, size = 5*5, replace = TRUE), ncol = 5)` how the desired output will look like? Eitherway, you can remove the rows afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something like @DavidArenburg's answer (converted from a comment):

```
idx <- which(upper.tri(m,diag=TRUE),arr.ind=TRUE)
v   <- pmin(m[idx], m[idx[,2:1]])

cbind(idx,min=v)[v>0,]
```

which gives

```
      row col min
 [1,]   1   1   1
 [2,]   2   2   3
 [3,]   1   3   2
 [4,]   2   3   2
 [5,]   3   3   4
 [6,]   1   4   5
 [7,]   2   4   1
 [8,]   4   4   1
 [9,]   1   5   5
[10,]   2   5   2
[11,]   4   5   5
[12,]   5   5   3
```

Comment: That's a very nice one. I was just posting a similar answer, but this nice use of `which` is much better. I was going with `tm <- t(m) ;
pmin(tm[upper.tri(tm, diag = TRUE)], m[upper.tri(m, diag = TRUE)])`